# Trying to find the square with minimum area inscribed in a Square of side L

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

A square has side length of L. Using the lagrange's multipliers, show that all squares inscribed in the square of side length of L, the square with minimum area has a side length of (sqrt(2)/2)L. 
I don't know how to solve it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to formulate the problem first.

the first thing is to write out objective function $$\min_{square \in C}  Area_{square} $$ where implicit constraint C is a set of all inscribed squares.

For inscribed square, its edge length should satisfy: $$l\cos \theta + l \sin\theta=L$$

Thus, the problem becomes $$\min_{\theta \in (0,\pi/2)} l*l=\min_{\theta \in (0,\pi/2)} \frac {L^2}{(\cos \theta+ \sin \theta)^2} $$

further,  $$\min \frac {L^2}{(\cos \theta+ \sin \theta)^2} $$

subject $$0 \lt \theta \lt \frac{\pi}2$$

Here is the starting point to use Lagrange multiplier method.